# Batch processing vs. sequence processing efficiency in R

Tags: r, performance, parsing, large-data, processing-efficiency

I'm working over a large database of chess games (approximately 4M games in PGN format) with the purpose of applying data analitycs tools for the first 15 moves of each game.

For that I'm using RStudio and so far I'm doing great. I've already created a parser to get game movements, and now I'm working on the code to reconstruct the position on the board at move 15.

My main concern now is the time it would require to process the 4M games and the efficiency of the code to do it. I mean, the code has to process 4M games * 15 moves * 2 (moves from black and white) = 120 M times. That's a lot. So I started looking up for the most effiency way of joining all the subprocess that I'm writting (parsing, coding the moves, etc), but so far I've not found any post related to this for R.

My two options (I dont know if there are others) are:

a) **batch processing**: parsing all the moves, store them in a dataframe, then go through each game in this dataframe to recreate the position on the board move by move until move 15 is reached

b) **sequence processing**: parse the first move of the game (move #1 from white), then store the position on the board, and loop over the next moves until move 15

So what approach would you recommend in terms of efficiency of the code? I'm thinking on processing time and computational cost.

Thank you

Comment: Hard to say from the outside, but my guess would be batch processing would be faster in R, especially if each step can be vectorized. Only way to know for sure would be to test.

Comment: Are you actually running into performance problems? 120 million rows is big but not out of the realm of possibility for direct processing in R, perhaps with the help of `data.table` or `bigmemory`. We could maybe help with more specifics on how the data is structured and what you want to do with it, but at the moment it sounds like [premature optimisation](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/perf-improve.html) to me.

Comment: Yeah, you are right Joe, maybe I'm getting too picky in terms of efficiency beforehand. I was just trying to do things right from the beggining to avoid rework later, but I think I'll take it easy and just end the script, test it and see what happens.